# Thymeleaf Template Engine do not follow the expression language

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Spring boot Maven dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>

@Service
public class MailContentBuilder {

    private TemplateEngine templateEngine;

    @Autowired
    public MailContentBuilder(TemplateEngine templateEngine) {
        this.templateEngine=templateEngine;
    }

    public String build(String templateName,String user,String email) throws IOException {
        Context context=new Context();
        context.setVariable("user", "Alpha");
        context.setVariable("email", "alpha@gmail.com");
        String test=templateEngine.process(templateName, context);
        return test;
    }
}
```

this is my mail sender method.

```
MimeMessage mimeMessage=javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
//mimeMessage.setContent(mailContentBuilder.build("changepassword","alpha","ema il@email.com"), "text/html");

MimeMessageHelper helper=new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage);
helper.setTo(auth0UserService.getUser(userid).getEmail());
helper.setFrom(fromUsername);
helper.setSubject("Password Change Confirmation");
helper.setText(mailContentBuilder.build("changepassword","alpha","email@email.com"), true);
javaMailSender.send(mimeMessage);
```

this is my template, in src/resources/templates

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Change password</title>
    </head>
    <body >
        helloooo th:text="${user}"
    </body>
</html>
```

This is what it sends, it does not follow the expression language, but writes to the page as it is. no use of variables.

```
helloooo th:text="${user}"
```

Comment: `th:text` should go on an element not somewhere in the text.

Comment: i used it as <span>helloooo th:text="${user}"</span>, same result

Comment: Thank you Deinum, i used it as an attribute to the tag. it worked now. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

th:text has to be an attribute to an html tag, so something like

```
<p th:text="helloooo ${user}" />
```

should work, judging from a glance at http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#using-texts